# Identifying and connecting ID's between tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables - one is storing article content and the other is storing article comments

The function I use to display these is:

```
function list_articles() { 
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT blog.content_id, blog.title, blog.content, blog.posted_by, blog.date, article_comments.comments, article_comments.comment_by
            FROM blog LEFT OUTER JOIN article_comments
            ON blog.content_id = article_comments.blog_id
            WHERE blog.content != ''
            ORDER BY blog.content_id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    
    $previous_blog_id = 0;
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($previous_blog_id != $row['content_id']) {
            echo "<h5 class='posted_by'>Posted by {$row['posted_by']} on {$row['date']}</h5> 
                <h1 class='content_headers'>{$row['title']}</h1> 
                <article>{$row['content']}</article>
                <hr class='artline'>";
            $previous_blog_id = $row['content_id'];
        }
        if (!empty($row['comment_by']) && !empty($row['comments'])) {
             echo "<div class='commented_by'>Posted by: {$row['comment_by']} </div> 
                   <div class='comments'>Comments: {$row['comments']}</div>
                   <hr class='artline2'>";
        }
    }
}
```

I use the below to insert comments into article_comments table:

```
function insert_comments($comments, $comment_by, $blog_id) {
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $comment_by = sanitize($comment_by);
    $comments = sanitize($comments);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO article_comments (comments, comment_by, blog_id)
            VALUES ('$comments', '$comment_by', '$blog_id')";
    mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
}
```

This works - it does the insertion, however I have no clue on how I could target the $blog_id variable when the user submits the post... The below is the form I use

```
<?php echo list_articles(); 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        insert_comments($_POST['comments'], $_POST['username'], 11);
        }
?>
<form method='post' action='' class='comments_form'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='your name... *' id='name'>
    <textarea name='comments' id='textarea' placeholder='your comment... *' cols='30' rows='6'></textarea> 
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='post' value='post'>
</form>
```

I bet you noticed that I've manually inserted 11 as a param for the last variable. This links to `blog_id` 11 (the foreign key) in my article_comments table. It is displaying the comment just fine.

Is there any way to target $blog_id without having to insert a number manually? Something like how I am targeting the $comments variable using `$_POST['comments']` ?

Also, even if I can target that, how do I know which post is the user commenting to? Should I give them the option to choose in a drop-down list ? That seems awkward.. but it's the only solution I can think of.

**EDIT:** My attempt at targeting blog_id in a hidden field:

```
function list_articles() { 
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT blog.content_id, blog.title, blog.content, blog.posted_by, blog.date, article_comments.comments, article_comments.comment_by
            FROM blog LEFT OUTER JOIN article_comments
            ON blog.content_id = article_comments.blog_id
            WHERE blog.content != ''
            ORDER BY blog.content_id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    
    $previous_blog_id = 0;
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($previous_blog_id != $row['content_id']) {
            echo "<h5 class='posted_by'>Posted by {$row['posted_by']} on {$row['date']}</h5> 
                <h1 class='content_headers'>{$row['title']}</h1> 
                <article>{$row['content']}</article>
                <hr class='artline'>";
            $previous_blog_id = $row['content_id'];
        }
        if (!empty($row['comment_by']) && !empty($row['comments'])) {
             echo "<div class='commented_by'>Posted by: {$row['comment_by']} </div> 
                   <div class='comments'>Comment: {$row['comments']}</div>
                   <hr class='artline2'>";
        }
        $sql2 = "SELECT FROM article_comments VALUES blog_id";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql2);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            echo "  <form method='post' action='' class='comments_form'>
                        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='your name... *' id='name'>
                        <textarea name='comments' id='textarea' placeholder='your comment... *' cols='30' rows='6'></textarea> 
                        <input type='hidden' name=blog_id' value='{$row['blog_id']}'>
                        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='post' value='post'>
                    </form>";
        }                
    }
}
```

sql2 and result2 part are the statements that are causing the error

**EDIT 2:**

I don't think the $sql2 is the correct approach. Code works fine now, but I'm back to square 1. For each comment inserted articles get duplicated.

```
<form method='post' action='' class='comments_form'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='your name... *' id='name'>
    <textarea name='comments' id='textarea' placeholder='your comment... *' cols='30' rows='6'></textarea> 
    <input type='hidden' name=blog_id' value='{$row['blog_id']}'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='post' value='post'>
</form>";
```

is there any way to target the blog_id without calling while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {} ? or at least, not calling it in the second while loop?

With the first piece of code I posted I get the following results:

```
Article title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- 
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 

-- BEGIN SECOND ARTICLE ON WEBPAGE 

Article title: LOREM IPSUM 2nd article
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- 
Name: User0
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: User1
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 
--------------------------------------
Name: User2
Comment: Great article! - 3rd comment
--------------------------------------
```

Which is exactly what I'm looking for. However I can only insert comments via the phpmyadmin interface, manually selecting the foreign key(blog_id).

I would like to be able to get the same results through a form:

```
Article title: LOREM IPSUM
Content: LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET....
-------------------------------------- //comments
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article!
--------------------------------------
Name: DSK
Comment: Great article! - 2nd comment 
-------------------------------------- // end comments

|-------------------------------------| // comments form
|Name: New User                       |
|Comment: New comment !               |
|                                     | 
|-------------------------------------|
[Submit]
```

When the user submits the form, his name and his comment gets submitted to the database into article_comments table. Also the foreign key (blog_id) should link to an existing article (which it does). I just need a way to target it in my function.

Does that make any sense?....

Comment: Why do you use another query $sql2 inside the while loop? Do not declare another query for finding the blog id, as it is already defined under the fkrst query. Use that directly in your hidden form field

Comment: That makes sense ! Thank you ! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a hidden form element inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?PHP echo $id;?>">
```

Then on submit you could access it with $_POST["blog_id"]

If I understood your question correctly that is.

Comment: I understand, that should work. However I do not want to insert a value manually. I want this value to be picked up from the database, from the $blog_id. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I've updated it so just assign $id with whatever results you need to fetch from table.

Comment: I've tried assigning the blog_id value fetched from the table but I get an error saying mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given - this has to be integer.. I've updated my question with the code I tried, also tried generating forms for every article. Please check

Comment: your $sql2 syntax is wrong. it should instead be  $sql2 = "SELECT blog_id FROM article_comments";   Values is used for insert statements

Comment: That works but I don't get the expected behavior. Instead, the articles get duplicated for every comment the user inserts. I believe the problem lays in my while loop. I have edited the question once more, trying to depict what I'm trying to accomplish. Please have a look

Comment: See my comment in the question. You'll find youristake